# I am getting a syntax Error near and keyword

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT   wrhwr.bl_id, 
         Count(wrhwr.wr_id) AS ct_wr_id 
FROM     ( 
                SELECT wrhwr.bl_id, 
                       wrhwr.wr_id, 
                       wrhwr.site_id, 
                       wrhwr.date_requested 
                FROM   wrhwr 
                WHERE 
                And    ( 
                              wrhwr.bl_id LIKE 'F0006440-B0001%') 
                AND    wrhwr.bl_id IN 
                       ( 
                                SELECT TOP 10 
                                         q.bl_id 
                                FROM     ( 
                                                  SELECT   bl_id, 
                                                           Count(wr_id) AS wrcnt 
                                                  FROM     afm.wrhwr 
                                                  GROUP BY bl_id) AS q 
                                WHERE    wrhwr.[status] IN ('Com', 
                                                            'I', 
                                                            'HL', 
                                                            'HP', 
                                                            'S') 
                                ORDER BY q.wrcnt DESC))wrhwr 
WHERE    (( 
                  And      ( 
                                    wrhwr.bl_id LIKE 'F0006440-B0001%') )) 
AND      ( 
                  wrhwr.site_id IN 
                  ( 
                         SELECT site_id 
                         FROM   site 
                         WHERE  state_id = 'JHB') 
         OR       wrhwr.site_id IS NULL) 
GROUP BY wrhwr.bl_id 
ORDER BY wrhwr.bl_id DESC
```

Comment: `WHERE   and` that's the mistake

Comment: If you formatted your query, it would be a lot easier to spot the simple error.

Comment: In fact this query is pretty awful, you have 4 nested levels of `SELECT` that almost certainly don't need to be nested.

Answer (score 0):

You have used AND + WHERE for the same statement which is giving you the error
like this

```
SELECT wrhwr.bl_id, 
                       wrhwr.wr_id, 
                       wrhwr.site_id, 
                       wrhwr.date_requested 
                FROM   wrhwr 
                WHERE 
                And    ( 
                              wrhwr.bl_id LIKE 'F0006440-B0001%')
```

Here, AND is not needed, since you have only 1 filter criteria,  try this

```
SELECT   wrhwr.bl_id,
         Count(wrhwr.wr_id) AS ct_wr_id
FROM     (
                SELECT wrhwr.bl_id,
                       wrhwr.wr_id,
                       wrhwr.site_id,
                       wrhwr.date_requested
                FROM   wrhwr
                WHERE wrhwr.bl_id LIKE 'F0006440-B0001%'
                AND    wrhwr.bl_id IN
                       (
                                SELECT TOP 10
                                         q.bl_id
                                FROM     (
                                                  SELECT   bl_id,
                                                           Count(wr_id) AS wrcnt
                                                  FROM     afm.wrhwr
                                                  GROUP BY bl_id) AS q
                                WHERE    wrhwr.[status] IN ('Com',
                                                            'I',
                                                            'HL',
                                                            'HP',
                                                            'S')
                                ORDER BY q.wrcnt DESC)
        )wrhwr
WHERE   wrhwr.bl_id LIKE 'F0006440-B0001%'
AND      (
                  wrhwr.site_id IN
                  (
                         SELECT site_id
                         FROM   site
                         WHERE  state_id = 'JHB')
         OR       wrhwr.site_id IS NULL)
GROUP BY wrhwr.bl_id
ORDER BY wrhwr.bl_id DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

This is at least readable...

```
SELECT wrhwr.bl_id, 
       Count(wrhwr.wr_id) AS ct_wr_id 
FROM ( SELECT wrhwr.bl_id, 
              wrhwr.wr_id, 
              wrhwr.site_id, 
              wrhwr.date_requested 
        FROM   wrhwr 
        WHERE AND ( wrhwr.bl_id LIKE 'F0006440-B0001%') 
          AND wrhwr.bl_id IN  ( SELECT TOP 10 q.bl_id 
                                FROM ( SELECT bl_id, 
                                              Count(wr_id) AS wrcnt 
                                       FROM afm.wrhwr 
                                       GROUP BY bl_id) AS q 
                                WHERE wrhwr.[status] IN ('Com','I','HL','HP','S') 
                                ORDER BY q.wrcnt DESC))wrhwr 
WHERE ((And(wrhwr.bl_id LIKE 'F0006440-B0001%') )) 
  AND ( wrhwr.site_id IN ( SELECT site_id 
                               FROM [site]
                               WHERE  state_id = 'JHB') 
   OR wrhwr.site_id IS NULL)
GROUP BY wrhwr.bl_id 
ORDER BY wrhwr.bl_id DESC;
```

And then, because it's **readable** you can easily see where the problems are (which I have commented out).

```
SELECT wrhwr.bl_id, 
       Count(wrhwr.wr_id) AS ct_wr_id 
FROM ( SELECT wrhwr.bl_id, 
              wrhwr.wr_id, 
              wrhwr.site_id, 
              wrhwr.date_requested 
        FROM   wrhwr 
        WHERE /*AND ( */wrhwr.bl_id LIKE 'F0006440-B0001%'/*) */
          AND wrhwr.bl_id IN  ( SELECT TOP 10 q.bl_id 
                                FROM ( SELECT bl_id, 
                                              Count(wr_id) AS wrcnt 
                                       FROM afm.wrhwr 
                                       GROUP BY bl_id) AS q 
                                WHERE wrhwr.[status] IN ('Com','I','HL','HP','S') 
                                ORDER BY q.wrcnt DESC))wrhwr 
WHERE /*((And(*/wrhwr.bl_id LIKE 'F0006440-B0001%'/*) )) */
  AND /*( */wrhwr.site_id IN ( SELECT site_id 
                               FROM [site]
                               WHERE  state_id = 'JHB') 
   OR wrhwr.site_id IS NULL/*)*/
GROUP BY wrhwr.bl_id 
ORDER BY wrhwr.bl_id DESC;
```

But, I'll be honest, that query is still awful, but after my SQL OCD kicked in to at least fix the "look" of the query, I have no interest in making it usable. :)